# Do I need separate controllers from component-like directives in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing custom element directives which are used to encapsulate HTML GUI or UI components. I am adding custom methods (that handles `ng-click` events, etc) in my `link` function such as:

```
app.directive('addresseseditor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            addresses: "="
        }, // isolated scope
        templateUrl: "addresseseditor.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.addAddress= function() {
               scope.addresses.push({ "postCode": "1999" });
           }

           scope.removeAddress = function (index) {
               scope.addresses.splice(index, 1);
           }

        }
    }
});
```

Is the `link` function correct place to define the methods or is it better to create a separate controller object, use `ng-controller` and define methods there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also define a controller per directive if you want. The main difference is that directives can share controllers (at the same level), controllers execute prior to compile, and controllers are injected (hence using the $). I think this is an accepted practice.

```
app.directive('addresseseditor', function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        addresses: "="
    }, // isolated scope
    templateUrl: "addresseseditor.html",
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $scope.addAddress= function() {
           $scope.addresses.push({ "postCode": "1999" });
       }

       $scope.removeAddress = function (index) {
           $scope.addresses.splice(index, 1);
       }

    }
}
});
```

You can have both link and controller... but you want to do any DOM stuff in the link because you know you're compiled.

This method also remains de-coupled since it's still part of your directive.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify "directives can share controllers (at the same level") part.

Comment: Sure, the 4th argument to the link function is actually a controller. This argument will be available if any other directive on the same element defines a controller in conjunction with the `require` property (actually I'm not sure that you MUST use require, I seem to recall it working without it). The classic example is `ng-model` which provides the `ngModelController`. This provides a way for cross-directive communication, provided they are on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are permanently coupling this with a controller & view, then I would say it doesn't really matter where you put it.

However, if you one day want to decouple the directive so you can reuse it, think of what functionality needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular [guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on directives reads:

> The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well
>   as updating the DOM. (...) This is where most of the directive logic
>   will be put.

I would follow the last part of that statement only if I had to write a directive that heavily manipulates the DOM. When all my directive does is render a template with some functionality, I use the `link` function to perform whatever basic DOM manipulation I need and the `controller` function to encapsulate the directive's logic. That way I keep things clearly separate (DOM manipulation from scope manipulation) and it seems consistent with the idea of "view-controller".

FWIW, I've implemented my first open source directive with those things in mind and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/src/ng-tags-input.js). Hopefully it might help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your elements functionality 'instance' specific place it in the link function, if you want to create an API across directives on an element create a controller function for it like master Rowny suggests.